# How to extract data from a snapshot or instances of AWS?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, debian

I cannot access one of my AWS instances via SSH or MySQL, it is inaccessible, but I know that the data contained in it is still intact, but I need some files that are within that instance, I would have access to that instance in any way just to recover that data?
I have some Snapshots of it, but as soon as I upload these Snapshots, I still have no access to the machine, because the Snapshots were generated after the problem in the isntancia, if somehow I could access the data of this Snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Launch a new EC2 instance and mount this volume as a secondary volume.

**On Linux EC2:** 
You can mount the volume using fstab, after assigning volume to EC2.

**On Windows EC2**
Use disk management utility to mount the volume.

Finally terminate the new instance after getting your files.

Comment: Further explanation: Detach the existing Amazon EBS volume from the existing Amazon EC2 instance, then attach it to the new EC2 instance. It will be an additional drive (not the _boot_ drive).